# Sax parser takes wrong tag Android

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

Below is my Saxparser classes that retrieve all elements within tag name "item".

```
   class SAXHelper {
      public HashMap<String, String> userList = new HashMap<String, String>();
      private URL url2;

      public SAXHelper(String url1) throws MalformedURLException {
       this.url2 = new URL(url1);
      }

      public RSSHandler parseContent(String parseContent) {
       RSSHandler df = new RSSHandler();
       try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(df);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url2.openStream()));
       } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       return df;
      }
     }

     class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

      private Post currentPost = new Post();
      StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

      @Override
      public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes atts) {

       chars = new StringBuffer();

       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

       }
      }

      @Override
      public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")
         && currentPost.getTitle() == null) {
        currentPost.setTitle(chars.toString());

        System.out.println("title1: " + currentPost.getTitle());

       }
       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("category")
         && currentPost.getCategory() == null) {
        currentPost.setCategory(chars.toString());

        System.out.println("category: " + currentPost.getCategory());

       }

       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")
         && currentPost.getDescription() == null) {
        currentPost.setDescription(chars.toString());

       }

       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")
         && currentPost.getLink() == null) {
        currentPost.setLink(chars.toString());

        System.out.println("link: " + currentPost.getLink());

       }

       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")
         && currentPost.getPubDate() == null) {
        currentPost.setPubDate(chars.toString());

        String x = currentPost.getPubDate();
        String last = x.substring(0, x.length() - 4);
        int start = last.length() - 8;
        int end = last.length() - 3;
        String result = x.substring(start, end);

        result = Stringreplace(result);
       }

       if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
        PostListNormal.add(currentPost);
        currentPost = new Post();
       }

      }

      @Override
      public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
       chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
      }

     }
```

Here is the xml tag to be extracted.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
      <channel>
        <title>matches en direct</title>
        <link>http://www.match.com/</link>
        <atom:link href="http://www.match.com/news,60,0,UTF-8,fulltext.rss" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <description>Foot 01 - NÂ°1 de l'actu du match, du mercato et des matches en direct</description>
        <language>fr-FR</language>
        <pubDate>Tue, 11 Mar 2014 06:12:38 GMT</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Tue, 11 Mar 2014 06:12:38 GMT</lastBuildDate>
        <category>Sports</category>
        <copyright>Â© 2011 match.com</copyright>
        <ttl>1</ttl>


        <item>
          <category>Espagne, match </category>
          <title>a</title>
          <link>aaaa</link>
          <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.match.com/foot-europeen/espagne/27e-j-les-match-definitifs,138131</guid>
          <description>
            match progress
          </description>
          <pubDate>Mon, 10 Mar 2014 22:52:02 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>

            <item>
          <category>x, match </category>
          <title>a</title>
          <link>aaaa</link>
          <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.match.com/foot-europeen/espagne/27e-j-les-match-definitifs,138131</guid>
          <description>
            match progress
          </description>
          <pubDate>Mon, 10 Mar 2014 22:52:02 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>

                <item>
          <category>x, match </category>
          <title>a</title>
          <link>aaaa</link>
          <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.match.com/foot-europeen/espagne/27e-j-les-match-definitifs,138131</guid>
          <description>
            match progress
          </description>
          <pubDate>Mon, 10 Mar 2014 22:52:02 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>

                    <item>
          <category>x, match </category>
          <title>a</title>
          <link>aaaa</link>
          <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.match.com/foot-europeen/espagne/27e-j-les-match-definitifs,138131</guid>
          <description>
            match progress
          </description>
          <pubDate>Mon, 10 Mar 2014 22:52:02 GMT</pubDate>
        </item>

      </channel>
      </rss>
```

When i ran the code, my result the tag for title prints

matches en direct,
a,
a,
a.

Expected result should be the 4 "a" elements.

For short the title in channel tag is printed then the first "item" tag is ignored, and finally it prints all tag items after the second tag item.

How can i prints all tag items only any idea. And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: So, your problem is that, the parser should parse 4 title element but it parsing 3 title elementd...am I right?

Comment: it should pass all tag elements from "item" tag only and neglect independent tag element in channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain a `boolean` to recognize that current element inside the `item` as below...

```
class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    private Post currentPost = new Post();
    StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

    boolean isItem = false;

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {

        chars = new StringBuffer();

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

            isItem = true;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title") && currentPost.getTitle() == null && isItem == true) {
            currentPost.setTitle(chars.toString());

            System.out.println("title1: " + currentPost.getTitle());

        }
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("category") && currentPost.getCategory() == null) {
            currentPost.setCategory(chars.toString());

            System.out.println("category: " + currentPost.getCategory());

        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description") && currentPost.getDescription() == null) {
            currentPost.setDescription(chars.toString());

        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link") && currentPost.getLink() == null) {
            currentPost.setLink(chars.toString());

            System.out.println("link: " + currentPost.getLink());

        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate") && currentPost.getPubDate() == null) {
            currentPost.setPubDate(chars.toString());

            String x = currentPost.getPubDate();
            String last = x.substring(0, x.length() - 4);
            int start = last.length() - 8;
            int end = last.length() - 3;
            String result = x.substring(start, end);

            result = Stringreplace(result);
        }

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            PostListNormal.add(currentPost);
            currentPost = new Post();

            isItem = false;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace your whole `RSSHandler` class with this class...then say, is it all right or not.

Comment: @Dimitri...Glad to hear it from you...then please, accept the answer with an upvote. :)

Comment: yes but one last question, say i want to print description values, will it take description from channel also or only description from items which is the expected outcome. does the code cope for title only or for all other tags because i am getting values from description in my log. thanks :)

Comment: if you don't apply the same condition with the `boolean` then `description` of `channel` will be parsed...apply the condition same as `title` in `endElement()`.